# Preventing the gas when Hydrogen peroxide is added to a detergent

Tags: hydrogen

In organic detergents, when I add Hydrogen peroxide to increase the stain removing feature a gas is produced.

How should I prevent the gas production process?

Comment: i don't think you can-? It's a catalytic process where Hydrogen peroxide is broken down into water and oxygen.

Comment: Well, when I want to put the detergent in plastic bottles, the oxygen makes the bottle's shape be awful! What can I do in order to prevent the bottle's shape to change?

Answer (score 1):

While hydrogen peroxide is fairly stable if pure in water solution, it can quickly break down to water plus oxygen in the presence of a catalyst such as transition metal ions--probably what is causing the gas evolution you observe. One approach you might try is to test other types of detergent - perhaps you can find one that does not catalyze breakdown of peroxide. Liquid facial soap or glycerine soap--or even dishwashing liquid--might be worth a try.

Another approach would be to mix the peroxide in right before use rather than try to store the mixture--the more dilute, the better.